# How to always show scroll bar in a listbox in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollviewer, visible

How to always show scroll bar in a listbox. If I delete Notscrolling visualstate of Scrollviewer. It always shows scrollbar only after scroll down happend. I want to show scrollbar when page loaded it should be visible always.

Pls Help me

Comment: i think u are not understand my question, I want show a scrollbar like in websites. It shows always.

Answer (score 5):

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
</ListBox>
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 3):

```
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <List Box ..>
                 </List Box>
       </ScrollViewer>
```

The Thing is the scroll bar moves up/down (or left/right) to the maximum of the child's(here listbox) width/height value. So ensure that the parent of the scrollviewer has greater height/width than the child's of the scroll viewer.

For your question : This is by design WP will not display scroll bar until you scroll it. It comes visible once you scroll the content of the scroll viewer and then disapperars automatically. If it is displaying ever (as you want to be) it must be an overhead.